# How many cubes are crossed by the diagonal (if HCF is not 1)?

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional

There is a big cube of dimension 110 * 154 * 385 made up of smaller 1 * 1 * 1 dimension cubes. A body (main) diagonal is drawn. How many smaller 1 * 1 * 1 cubes will it cut?

Comment: You may first want to try this already posted question before coming to this one:
 
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53313/how-many-cubes-are-crossed-by-a-diagonal

Comment: i like the question but why did u answer it by urself?

Comment: why do people think this is off-topic? I believe this is a good puzzle question in some way.

Comment: It's off topic because this is a standard maths question. I mean, this idea [is not even original](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1996_AIME_Problems/Problem_14)

Comment: @Oray: Am making a logic test paper. Just created this question over a similar one posted here, with HCF = 1. Wanted to know, if my answer is correct. Thanks for liking it.

Comment: A ***cube*** with dimensions 110 × 154 × 385?  Surely you mean a [rectangular parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped), a.k.a. a [rectangular cuboid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid).  … … … …  P.S. What does the Hamilton Community Foundation (in Ontario, Canada) have to do with this puzzle?  (I assumed that you weren’t talking about the Hawaii Correctional Facility.)

Answer (score 1):

Above answer is brilliant! Another way to approach this kind of question is: first take HCF to shrink the big cube into the smallest one with same ratio on 3 dimensions. Usually the smallest cub is manageable; then take the shadow of body (main) diagonal on each of 3 faces. It will reduce to standard # of squares cut by diagonal on each rectangle; then mark the square which got crossed on 3 faces. It will help figure out # of cubs to be crossed. It takes more time this way if you dcan't remember the formula above

Comment: I don't really understand; could you elaborate further? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Since there has not been any response as of now, here is my solution without a lot of explanation.

For this question, the answer must be:
(HCF(x,y,z)) * (1 + (a-1) + (b-1) + (c-1) - (HCF(a,b) - 1) - (HCF(a,c) - 1) - (HCF(b,c) - 1))

where a = x/(HCF(x,y,z) and so on.

or,

11 * (1+9+13+34-1-4-6) = 506

Comment: You posted your answer 2 hours and 14 minutes after you posted the question!  [SE] has users all around the world, in different time zones, and people who are in the same time zone may have different daily schedules / rhythms (e.g., might work the night shift).  You should wait 24 to 48 hours before posting your answer to your own question. … … … … P.S. Answers “without a lot of explanation” are not popular here.  In case my comment on the question was too subtle for you: You should say what HCF is.